# What is the expected page generation time for simple page in symfony 2 sonata?

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

Hey guys I'm playing with sonata and trying to create a simple backend for a few related models. But my pages are generated in about a second for quite a simple page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNpsa.png

Most of the time takes twig templates processing. But event on simple non-sonata pages (in this project) it takes quite a while to generate a page https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvyCM.png

I wrote a simple twig extension to measure time in prod env and it doesn't actually differ much from dev.
I have quite powerful laptop (i7 - 8 cores with 8 gb ram, NON-SSD 7200 rpm hard) and I even tried to deploy the project on the powerful server and the time also didn't differ much (about 10-15%).

Am I doing something wrong? I use php 5.6 on local machine with opcache enabled

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=0
opcache.memory_consumption=400 
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
```

What is page generation time for your real projects?

Comment: I have some horrible results with sonata also. You can gain some 14% with the c extension for twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html#installing-the-c-extension. See the benchmark here: http://www.strangebuzz.com/post/2013/02/21/Twig-C-extension-benchmark

Comment: According to Twig documentation templates are rendered to plain PHP code for best performance. Is it possible that caching is not enabled or something prevents it from working?

Comment: yes I've heard about twig-c-extension but haven't tried it yet. Well I can't find any issues with cache, here is entry script https://github.com/ekonoval/sym_fos_user_sandbox/blob/master/web/app.php